# What's the programmatic equivalent of "defaults read"?

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

When I do `defaults read` at the command line, I get over 6000 lines of keys.  When I enumerate `UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()` in a program (non-sandboxed), I get only about 50 lines of values.

What's the Foundation version of `defaults read`?  How do I get *all* the NSUserDefaults keys in a program?

Answer (score 1):

`defaults read` without any domain argument reads all domains for the current user. `UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()` reads just the current application's domain.

I have no idea why you'd want to read all domains, but you can do it using the [CFPreferences API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/preferences_utilities). You start by calling `CFPreferencesCopyApplicationList(kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost)` to get all of the application domains (including the global domain, `kCFPreferencesAnyApplication`). Note that this is deprecated without any replacement that I'm aware of. Then, you iterate through those and call `CFPreferencesCopyMultiple(nil, eachAppIDInTurn, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost)`.

Comment: In the most recent version of Swift `CFPreferencesCopyApplicationList` will return `Unsupported API`, in addition to being deprecated; I believe you are correct, there does not appear to be a replacement.

Comment: "I have no idea why you'd want to read all domains" -- being able to write a utility like defaults(1) is one!  Isn't it strange that Apple's new programming language is compatible with C, but can't do this?

Comment: The first call gives me two domains, "com.apple.security_common" and "com.apple.security".  The second call, on each of these, gives a CFDictionaryRef with 0 items.

Comment: The domains returned by the first call don't look like `kCFPreferencesAnyApplication` at all.  If I specifically ask for that key with the second call, I get 27 keys, and the same keys as "defaults read" returns for "Apple Global Domain".  Still no idea how to get the rest of them, though.

Comment: Works here for me, but I'm still running Sierra. You sure you're not sandboxed?

Comment: Whoa, you're right.  I didn't add any Capabilities, and had no idea that Xcode defaulted to Sandboxed these days (crazy!).  With no sandbox, it provides many more keys.  It still doesn't look 100% the same as "defaults read", though.  Investigating...

Comment: You may need to try all permutations of (`CurrentUser`, `AnyUser`) x (`CurrentHost`, `AnyHost`).